# How to set up Ruby / RoR methods autocomplete with sublimecodeintel in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, sublimetext3

Goal: Using sublimecodeintel + ctags, have Sublime text 3 autocomplete show available methods for each class.

Example:
  typing "[1,2,3]." should give options like
to_s
                 .to_a
                 .to_ary
                 .empty?

I have searched extensively on the topic for the past couple of days. the idea is to make sublime text aware of the RVM-Ruby being used for the project and have autocomplete prompt the available methods.
This isn't a sublime text 3 (build 3047, osx mavericks), sublimecodeintel or ctags issue.
Sublimecodeintel is verified working - it autocompletes for classes defined in project.
ctags have been installed using brew. and the built up tags file contains tags from across the project. Its more of a correct set of settings / order of installing the plugins to get it working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the [CTags](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CTags) plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want this: go in View -> Syntax -> Rails
for the use highlights CTRL+SPACE

Comment: the rails syntax shows / highlights correctly. but the autocomplete (CTRL+SPACE) doesn't suggest basic Ruby / ROR methods for any objects. For example a boolean by default has a .nil? method.

Comment: Sorry my english is not very good,: You want for use the Ruby basic methods with ROR syntax?

Comment: @MattDMo, yes i tried ctags didn't work. So I did a clean reinstall (uninstalled the application & removed "sublime text 3" folder from application support) before installing ST3, package control & codeintel again. codeintel now picks up project specific ruby and loads ruby core library. @ Bruno Casali, no problem. thanks for taking the effort.